# With Apify/Puppeteer, crawl all URLs except those that contain a word

Tags: puppeteer, apify

With Apify/Puppeteer, how can I crawl all pages except those that include a certain word?

Inside of the handlePageFunction, the original code looks like this

```
        await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
            requestQueue,
            page,
            pseudoUrls: [
                baseurl + '[.*]',
            ],
        });
```

This crawls all pages. If I want to avoid page URLs that contain "foo", is there anyway I could adjust something within pseudoUrls to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Apify documentation for PseudoUrls](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/pseudo-url):

> A PURL is simply a URL with special directives enclosed in [] brackets. Currently, the only supported directive is [RegExp], which defines a JavaScript-style regular expression to match against the URL.

Therefore you can include a regex that would prevent matching urls that contain `foo` by embedding a regular expression with negative lookahead at the front, like this:

```js
await Apify.utils.enqueueLinks({
    // ...
    pseudoUrls: [
        '[(?!.*foo)]' + baseurl + '[.*]',
    ],
});
```

What this does:

- the square brackets `[` + `]` mean that this part of the pseudoUrl is an embedded regex
- `(?!` + `)` denominates a negative lookahead group in a regular expression. This means that **if the sub-regex contained inside matches, a match is refused for the main (outer) regex**.
- `.*` means that any characters may precede the string that you want to avoid matching
- `foo` is the string you want to avoid matching

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for this:

1. As mentioned in the previous answer - you could either use `pseudoUrls` option of `enqueueLinks` (the option you are currently using in your example).
2. Additionally - you could use the `transformRequestFunction`, where you could do a simple check (something like `if (!/foo/.test(request.url)) return request;`) to filter the requests.

Here's the [link](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/utils#utilsenqueuelinksoptions) to `enqueueLinks` documentation where these options are explained in detail.